# Sending several page requests before receiving the first response python-urllib

Tags: python, http, urllib2, urllib

I am writing a python program to crawl Reddit(why is a bit complicated). The program uses a urllib http request to grab search pages, and then parses them. This takes an exceeding amount of time because of the gap between submitting a request and getting the page back (around 10s even on a university internet connection). Is there any way to send several requests at once and them process them all once the responses come back?

Comment: make asynchronous requests via multiple process and process the records

Comment: Are you suggesting I multi-thread the application?